# How to make, three a .dae mesh object to interactive?

Tags: three.js, interactive

How to make, three.js a ColladaLoaded mesh object to interactive? I try something
raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.mydae ); also raycaster.intersectObjects(mydae );
they not work. I use http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes to my experiments by altering it. Is there on web some sample where .dae mesh is made to an interactive?(nne)

Answer (score 1):

I used this

```
intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
if (intersects.length>0){
    obj = intersects[ 0 ].object.parent.parent.parent;
}
```

to get obj.name since objects instead of scene.children returned undefined

Answer (score 0):

Add the recursive flag like so:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
```

three.js r.71